# "Local" CSS Media Queries for modular items design

Tags: css, resize, media-queries, adaptive-design

Recently I've been asked to build a component element for a website. This component should be fully resizable. What I want is to take advantage of the CSS3 media queries for making different size layouts. It works well if component initially takes whole page for a display, but if it is put inside of the div with 50% width then it's size changes in half, but that is not reflecting in it's inner layout. What I want is the same behaviour that Media Queries provide but for a component oriented approach. Is it possible with CSS?

Comment: Please provide your full existing code. You can include a jsfiddle or jsbin link, or alternatively use either `backticks` or 4 spaces to include a code snippet.

Comment: Currently not possible … but others have though about this too already: http://www.jonathantneal.com/blog/thoughts-on-media-queries-for-elements/

Comment: with javascript: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/06/25/media-queries-are-not-the-answer-element-query-polyfill/